# Is there any sign utility method in Java or C#?

Tags: java, c#

I know this is simple, but want to check is there any sign method which can

sign(n) when n is odd , return -1, n is even, return 1.

I know it is pretty simple to implement myself, but just to check if there is already an existing one.

Comment: Do you mean a *sign* function like [Math.Sign](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sign(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET, or an odd/even function?

Comment: No, It is not I am looking, please see my question.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a standard method...

Comment: You want `return n % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1`. There isn't a framework method to do it.

Comment: yes,exactly like the above, but can change to n%2 == 0? -1: 1

Answer (score 0):

Sign and odd/even are different functions.  A sign function (if it existed) would return a result based on a number is negative or positive, not odd or even.

For Java:

- there is no method in the standard libraries to test if a number is odd or even
- there are static `signum` methods in the relevant primitive wrapper classes (e.g. `Integer`) that will return -1, 0 or 1 depending on the sign of the argument.